# What does the AUTO_COMMIT=0 mean when executing a sql file into a database?

Tags: navicat

When executing a sql file for a database then there is the dialog box containing the checkboxes continue on error, use multiple queries at the same time, set AUTO_COMMIT=0

I want to know what does the AUTO_COMMIT=0 mean when executing a sql file into a database.

Comment: I assume you found your answer after a month, but ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocommit. Or is there anything in particular you do not understand about the autocommit feature?

Comment: So if AUTO_COMMIT is 0 then it means that AUTO_COMMIT is turned off ?

Comment: Yes, turned off for the executed file.